# How to union all +1 table on this?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**CURRENT SQL QUERY:**

```
SELECT question_ID,autor_id,titulo,pergunta,curtidas,comentario_ID,comentario_question_ID,comentario_autor_id,comentario,comentario_curtidas FROM
perguntador as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN perguntadorrespostas
   ON perguntadorrespostas.comentario_question_id = a.question_id
UNION ALL
SELECT question_ID,autor_id,titulo,pergunta,curtidas,comentario_ID,comentario_question_ID,comentario_autor_id,comentario,comentario_curtidas FROM perguntador as b
RIGHT OUTER JOIN perguntadorrespostas
    ON perguntadorrespostas.comentario_question_id = b.question_id order by question_ID desc
```

**NEED ADD:**

```
SELECT Nome,NULL...... FROM login
INNER (OR OTHER) JOIN perguntador ON perguntador.autor_id = login.user_id
```

**IT'S POSSIBLE?**

Some details:

tried in various ways, but `SELECT * FROM login` "intrude" with other "SELECT"...(example: [question_ID] becomes [Nome] )

required row:

[Nome]

in `var_dump -> [Nome]=> [NULL]`

Final result: Notice: Undefined index: Nome in....

**I think it complicated, but it costs I try to see if some genius understood**

**this "confusion cake"**

P.S: Any order details will be entertained, thanks!

**Update 1: Table login**

- Nome
- userphoto
- and more 7 columns unnecessary

**Table perguntador**

- question_ID
- autor_ID
- titulo
- pergunta
- curtidas

**Table perguntadorrespostas**

- comentario_ID
- comentario_question_ID
- comentario_autor_id
- comentario
- comentario_curtidas

**graphic explication**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiQq.png

Comment: Since you need `Nome`, and you said `question_ID` = `Nome`, can you change your current query to - `SELECT question_ID as Nome,...`?

Comment: In the 1st queries, or just your query you want to add? ie. `SELECT question_ID as Nome ... FROM perguntador as a ... UNION ALL SELECT question_ID as Nome ... FROM perguntador as b ... UNION ALL SELECT Nome as Nome ... FROM login ...`?

Comment: Will create a graphic explication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` your `login` table to your `perguntador` table query's and add your `Nome` to the `SELECT` -

```
SELECT 
user_ID, Nome, userphoto, question_ID, autor_id, titulo,pergunta, curtidas,comentario_ID, comentario_question_ID, comentario_autor_id, comentario, comentario_curtidas 
FROM
perguntador as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
perguntadorrespostas
ON 
perguntadorrespostas.comentario_question_id = a.question_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
login
ON 
a.autor_id = login.user_id 

UNION ALL
SELECT 
user_ID, Nome, userphoto, question_ID, autor_id, titulo, pergunta, curtidas, comentario_ID, comentario_question_ID, comentario_autor_id, comentario, comentario_curtidas 
FROM 
perguntador as b
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
perguntadorrespostas
ON 
perguntadorrespostas.comentario_question_id = b.question_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
login
ON 
perguntadorrespostas.comentario_autor_id = login.user_id  
ORDER BY
question_ID desc
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaanksss I LOVE YOUUUUUUUUUUUU MAN <3 , YOU SAVE MY LIFE

Comment: Man your code worked , but no displaying comentario_autor_id where name